# Cards that untap lands on opponents' turns

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I used to use [Prophet of Kruphix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProphet%20of%20Kruphix%5d) in my commander deck, but it is now banned.

While giving all creatures flash is nice, but I really used it for it's land untap ability. Are there any other cards that let me untap my lands on other player's turns?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do a quick search for [keywords like 'untap' + 'other player'](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22untap%22%20o%3A%22other%20player%22&v=card&s=cname) to find some cards.

This'll put you on [Seedborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeedborn%20Muse%5d). She's the original Prophet of Kruphix, but hasn't been hit by a ban because she doesn't have that super-juicy "flash" clause. (And because being mono-green means she props up more diverse archetypes than a UG card does.)

Is that your only option? Not quite: try other keywords (maybe filter down to your colors and search 'untap' + 'land' or 'untap' + 'permanent').

Some highlights that you're likely to miss unless you try a lot of search permutations:

- [Awakening](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAwakening%5d) is a green enchantment that untaps everyone's stuff. (And allows heavily-instant-speed decks to double-dip mana on their own turn.)
- [Patron of the Orochi](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPatron%20of%20the%20Orochi%5d) is a big green creature that you can use to untap all your *green* creatures and *forests* each turn. (And can also be used to double up your mana on your own turn.)

Comment: Damn... Seedborn muse is actually so much better because your creatures essentially gain a better version of Vigilance.

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 other options for you:

1. http://www.mtgsalvation.com/cards/tenth-edition/13990-seedborn-muse
2. http://www.mtgsalvation.com/cards/stronghold/4946-awakening

Answer (score 1):

Another option (though unfortunately just for a single land) is Urban Burgeoning from Return to Ravnica. I haven't looked it up myself, but im pretty sure there are other cards that untap on opponent turns if you widen your search for "land", "untap", "upkeep", and "player".